# RKUrl class doesn't exist in latest RestKit

Tags: iphone, ios, restkit

I'm having problem to use RESTKIT. I have installed everything perfectly, I have been following [Raywenderlich Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13097/intro-to-restkit-tutorial)  but in latest restkit RKURL doesn't exist; even RKObjectLoader is also not there. Please can any one tell what are the replacement of these classes? I have checked on [restkit.org](http://restkit.org) & github but not able to find out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

RKURL is part of 0.10 RESTKIT.it is not part of 0.20 RESTKIT anymore.
RestKit now use AFNetworking for more info which classes & methods have upgraded or eliminated in 0.20 version of Restkit follow this official link [restkit upgrading from 0.10 to 0.20](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Upgrading-from-v0.10.x-to-v0.20.0)

Comment: can anyone comment on how to update that tutorial with regards to RKURL?

Comment: can you just replace RKURL with NSURL?

Answer (score 0):

According to restkit [upgrading from 0.10 to 0.20](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Upgrading-from-v0.10.x-to-v0.20.0) just use NSURL like this :

```
RKObjectManager* objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```